# RealmSwiftで保存したオブジェクトから一つの変数の配列を取り出す方法

Tags: swift, realm

現在、データの保存にRealmSwiftを使用しておりまして、
下記のように一つのオブジェクトにいくつかの型のデータを保存しています。

```
class Sample: Object {
    dynamic var number:CGFloat = 0
    dynamic var string:String = ""
}
```

この時に

```
var floatArr:[CGFloat] = []
```

上記のようなCGFloat型の配列に"number"のオブジェクトだけを存在するだけ取り出す。
ということは可能でしょうか？

参考になりそうなサイトが見つからず、
公式サイトなどを見ながら実装を試みているのですが、
なかなかうまく実装できません。

Answer (score 1):

`Results`に対して、`valueForKey(_:)`または`valueForKeypath(_:)`を利用して特定のプロパティの集合だけを取り出す、ということが可能です。

```
let numbers = realm
    .objects(Sample.self)
    .valueForKey("number")
```

このとき、`numbers`の型は`NSArray`なので`CGFloat`の配列として扱うにはキャストが必要です。

```
if let numbers = numbers as? [CGFloat] {
    ...
}
```

もう一つの解として、`map()`を利用する方法もあります。

```
let numbers = realm
    .objects(Sample.self)
    .map { $0.number }
```

もし、最終的にやりたいことが合計や平均を出したい、ということであればわざわざ配列にせずに、直接`sum()`や`average()`メソッドを利用することもできます。

余談ですが、`CGFloat`はデバイスによって型が変わる（32bitまたは64bit）のでRealmに保存するデータ型としてはお勧めしません。例えば、32bitのデバイスから64bitのデバイスに変更してデータを復元するとデータ型が異なるのでマイグレーションが必要になります。Double（またはFloat）を使いましょう。

Comment: kishikawa katsumi様　ご回答ありがとうございます。.valueForKeyを使ってデータを取り出せば良いのですね！ご教授いただいた内容で実装できそうです！ありがとうございました。